# Converting ResultSet to array of to int

Tags: java, arrays, resultset

I am trying to convert `ResultSet` to array of `int`, that because the method I have returns `int[]`:

```
public static int[] GetPathIDsFromDB (String Dbnum, int objectid) throws SQLException{
    String selectSQL = "SELECT ID FROM " + Dbnum + ".tabName where ObjectID=?";
    dbConnection = getDBConnection();
    preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
    preparedStatement.setInt(1 , objectid);
    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();  
    //int [] rsIDs = new rs.count;
    int [] rsIDs = null;
    while (rs.next()) {
        rsIDs=rs.getInt(1); // the error int cannot be converted to int[]
    }
    return rsIDs;
}
```

How can I convert that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add each result from the `ResultSet` to the array and for that you need a counter variable as the index of the array.

Also, initialize your `int[]` array properly because currently its just initialized to `null`.

```
int[] rsIDs = new int[size]; // decide the size
int counter = 0; // counter
while (rs.next()) {
    rsIDs[counter++] = rs.getInt(1);
}
```

And if you do not know the size before hand, then it is better to use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of an `array`.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would put them into a list, then convert to an array at the end.

```
List<Integer> rsIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (rs.next()) {
  rsIds.add(rs.getInt(1));
}
return rsIds.toArray(new Integer[](rsIds.size());
```

It should automatically convert the Integer[] to an int[] for you via autoboxing.

---

Seeing as how I'm an idiot, and that doesn't work, this is how I would then do it:

```
rs.last();
int[] rsIds = new int[rs.getRow()];
rs.beforeFirst();
int counter = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
  rsIds[counter] = rs.getInt(1);
  counter++;
}
```

This won't work if the ResultSet is of type TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, you would need to change the scroll type for it to work.

Comment: @M21B8 - Are you sure about that? Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: Auto-unboxing converts `Integer` to `int`, but not `Integer[]` to `int[]`. Try it yourself and you see compile error.

Comment: Ah crapsticks. That'll teach me to try and code off the top of my head! New solution added above.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve the problem:

1. Execute another query to extract size first, extract size and then create array of this size:

   ```
   String sizeQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM " + Dbnum + ".tabName where ObjectID=?";
   ```
2. Create an `List` of `Integer`, add result to it (as M21B8 described), and then convert it to an `int[]`, as:

   ```
   int size = list.size();
   int[] result = new int[size];
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       result[i] = list.get(i);
   }

   return result;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could make your life easier and use an ArrayList:

```
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();      
ArrayList<Integer> rsIDs = new ArrayList<>();
while (rs.next()) {
    rsIDs.add(rs.getInt(1));
}
```

If you still want it in an array you can create it afterwards.

Comment: the array need a line per row, not per column, so option 1 won't work. Option 2 is what i suggested, and he needs an int[] not Integer[], so this won't work either